# Stability of transfer functions with internal delay

Tags: control-theory, approximation-theory, transcendental-equations, stability-in-odes

I would like to know what the best method is for finding stability of transfer functions that have internal delays. Basically I have a transfer function of the form:

$\frac{f(s) e^{-st}}{g(s) + h(s) e^{-st}}$

where $f(s), g(s), h(s)$ are rational functions with real coefficients.

I've looked at the Nyquist criterion, but its hard to get it into the necessary form, and I've also looked at Pade approximations. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to validate whether the Pade approximation is accurate enough to give answers on the stability of the transfer function. I've also found some articles on Mikhailov stability criterion, though I'm not sure if its applicable in this case.

Comment: It might be hard to say anything without knowing the form of $f(s)$, (and especially) $g(s)$ and $h(s)$.

Comment: i've updated the question to restrict the form of the function

Comment: this still hasn't been answered, but in case anyone else stumbles on the question, I've made some progress by looking at root crossings with respect to the delay $t$ and using the Routh criterion

Comment: Write your transfer function in the form $G(s) / (1 + G(s) H(s))$, then notice that it can be seen as a feedback $H(s)$ around a transfer function $G(s)$. The loop transfer function is $G(s) H(s)$; now use Nyquist.